# What is the name of the branch of Probability that deals with the experiments with Uncountably Infinite outcomes?

Tags: probability

I am having lectures that is repeatedly discussing the experiments like the following:

> We draw two points $p$ and $q$ at random from the interval $[-1, 1]$. Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ denote the roots of the equation $x^2 + px + q = 0$.
>
> Find the probability that:
>
> (a) $x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb R$
>
> (b) ${x_1}^2 + {x_2}^2 < 1$

My instructor says that, this is called `Continuous Probability`. But, I am not finding any chapter or topic of the name `Continuous Probability` in any books of introductory probability.

There are some topics named `Continuous Random Variable`, or, `Continuous Probability Distribution`. But, they seems to be not dealing with these types of problems. Am I missing something?

Where can I find materials to study and solve these `Continuous Probability` problems?

I am in trouble. Please, help me.

Comment: Are you familiar with continuous  uniform distribution?

Comment: These random variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ indeed have a continuous probability distribution, on $\mathbb{C}$.  There are two kinds of random variables in most introduction to probability texts, discrete---like Bernoulli, or Poisson random variables---and continuous, like the continuous uniform distribution, exponential and normal.

Answer (score -1):

It's called a geometric probability, most of the introductory books cover this topic as an example but they don't dedicate much effort to it. If you want a dedicated book, you may look at (for example): Klain, Rota, *Introduction to Geometric Probability*, CUP (available online).

Comment: Not sure the OP describes the restricted field of geometric probability.